# Sending bytes via a class, over socket. For some reason socket.sendall(data) appends bytes to data. Making decoding on the other end impossible

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, byte

Like the title says, whenever I try to send data, socket.sendall(arg) prepends a bunch of bytes to the data. It seems to be, in least in part, the attributes from the class where the method is defined.

Here are the relevant bits of the code:

```
class Client:
    NICK = ''
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 65000
    BUFSIZ = 4096
    CONNECTION = None

    def __init__(self, nick_name):
        try:
            self.NICK = nick_name
            ...

    def send_n(self, data):
        print("Sending:", data)
        self.CONNECTION.sendall(data)

class Server:
    def relay_game(self):
        players = self.HANDLER.recv(self.BUFSIZ)
        print("Received:", players)
        print("SERVER SIDE DATA:", players.decode())

def run_handler():
    h = client.Client("HANDLER")
    data = (b'test')
    print("Calling with:", data)
    h.send_n(data)
```

And here is the output:

```
Calling with: b'test'
Sending: b'test'
Received: b'\x80\x03X\x07\x00\x00\x00HANDLERq\x00.test'
```

As you can see, a bunch of bytes as been prepended to "data" while being sent from the Client function "send_n" to the Server function "relay_game". The reason I said parts of the bytes are from the attributes of Client is because the NICK value, "HANDLER" in this case, is present in on the received part.

Anyone know why this is happening? And what a possible solution would be to solve it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I got some hints elsewhere and figured it out.

There was a pickled message sent containing the literal 'HANDLER' previously, which was left unreceived by the server. When the server then later started listening both messages was sent.